# Statistical test for feature selection

Tags: feature-selection

Suppose I have a procedure to select K features out of M. I repeat the procedure N times on, say bootstrapped datasets, and count how many times feature #1 appeared among selected, denote k1, how many times feature #2 appeared, denote k2, etc.

Question 1: What would be a suitable statistical test to check from the counts k1,k2,...,kM, whether the selection procedure is random or not?

Question 2: What would be a suitable statistical test to check from ki/N, whether feature i appears ki/N times by chance, or appears more/less frequently than it would simply by chance?

Question 3: is there a theoretically grounded way to set N, i.e. how many times to repeat the selection procedure, for the test to be conclusive?

Comment: This is exactly what is done in random forests.  Have you looked at that literature?  http://www.statistik.uni-dortmund.de/useR-2008/slides/Strobl+Zeileis.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I was not aware of this line of work on decision trees, interesting. They consider permutation tests, the outcome is measured via classification accuracy. In my case, it is problematic to use classification accuracy, since I have very few observations (16), and I would like to use as many for model training. For measuring the classification accuracy I would need to reserve a test set, which would not be used in training. So I am wondering if there are any tests that use feature counts directly, this way I do not need to reserve a test set.

Comment: There is a variation of cross validation that rotates through each observation excluding it alone from the training.  It then can look at the ensemble of fits, and the ensemble of errors and, in effect, allows all the points to contribute to the fit AND all the points to contribute to the validation without over-fitting.

Comment: Here are some more options:  http://linus.nci.nih.gov/techreport/TechReport_Molinaro.pdf , http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947310001064 , http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6360017

Comment: Chapter 7 of the following also speaks to some of this. http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/